# Access iPhone power button in app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I just have a simple question regarding the button on the upper right corner of the iPhone (power button). Is there anyway you can receive notification from it when it´s being pushed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `–applicationWillResignActive:` and `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` application delegate methods are the closest you can get, although they can be triggered for other events such as an incoming call. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I wanted to achieve the same functinallity as the time app, where pressing the hold/power-button will trigger snooze. Guess that went through the window...

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly access the hold button, that is reserved to Apple and must always behave the same independent of app. Because of this you are not allowed to use it to do other things.

However, as Mike had said, you can get information about when the app is going to go to sleep or become active, which can be triggered by pressing the hold button